# Error with St_geomfromtext in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, insert

When I try to insert a point into a point layer, getting the coordinates with the following line:

```
select avg(st_x(the_geom)), avg(st_y(the_geom)) from centroide;
```

I get an error when I run the following code to insert into:

```
insert into centroide(the_geom, comarca_nombre) 
VALUES ( st_geomfromtext('POINT (231029.40356766043 4345690.6726352)', 25830), 'CENTRO' )
```

```
Error SQL: insert into centroide(the_geom, comarca_nombre)  VALUES ( st_geomfromtext('POINT (231029.40356766043 4345690.6726352)', 25830), 'CENTRO' ) devolvió 0 [ERROR:  el valor nulo en la columna «id» de la relación «centroide» viola la restricción de no nulo
DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (null, 0101000020E66400007AAE813AAB330C4183740CABD6935041, null, null, CENTRO).]
```

```
The The failing row contains (null, 0101...
```

[image]

Comment: The st_geomfromtext part is OK but we can't know what the table into which you want to do insert looks like.

Comment: There you are, I hope you can help me with this info

Comment: I edited your question body to correctly format those code snippets - the needed details are there. In fact, the error message is pretty precise - what about it do you not understand? Your `id` column is not auto-incremental and thus you need to provide a value for it, to not violate the `NOT NULL` constraint.